# How to make viewcontroller to show as bottom page in ios10 swift3?

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I have one view controller with button, if I click on button it should display the bottom view controller (like bottom page in Android):

[image: viewcontroller]

[image: viewcontroller]

I have these two demo view controllers, if I click on button second view controller should display only details view and it should popup from bottom of first view controller.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by `bottom page in Android`. Can you be little more specific? Add code of what you have tried so far. Or image of what you exactly want to achieve.

Comment: I think u need Tabbarcontroller or else

Comment: Can you share screenshot of Android bottom page?

Comment: I have added two screen shots and explained about my question, please check once and let me know the solution.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @ Toby Speight 
thank you for the advice, i have tried with the code which i have searched on google, its related transition but didn't work so finally i have posted here to know the exact procedure and how to do it

Answer (score 1):

For achieving it you should add second view controller as child view controller and animate it from bottom.
Adding child:

```
   let secondViewControllerInstance = SecondViewController() // or by Storyboard 
    instantiate method
    self.addChildViewController(secondViewControllerInstance)
    let initialRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: SCREEN_HEIGHT-200, width: SCREEN_WIDTH,
                             height: 200)
    secondViewControllerInstance.view.frame = rect
    secondViewControllerInstance.view.center.y += 100
    self.view.addSubview(secondViewControllerInstance.view)
    secondViewControllerInstance.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    //Animate center y
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        secondViewControllerInstance.view.center.y -= 100
    }
```

Tweak heights and widths according to your requirement.